# How does one create a pytorch data loader with a custom hugging face data set without having errors?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets, huggingface-hub

Currently my custom data set gives None indices in the data loader, but NOT in the pure data set. When I wrap it in pytorch data loader it fails.

Code is in [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sbs95as_66mtK9VK_vbaE9gLE-Tjof1-?usp=sharing) but will put it here in case colab dies someday:

```
pip install datasets
pip install pytorch
pip install transformers
```

then run

```
token = None
batch_size = 10
from datasets import load_dataset
import torch
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
if tokenizer.pad_token_id is None:
  tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
probe_network = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2")
device = torch.device(f"cuda:{0}" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
probe_network = probe_network.to(device)

# -- Get batch from dataset
from datasets import load_dataset
# path, name = 'brando/debug1_af', 'debug1_af'
path, name = 'brando/debug0_af', 'debug0_af'
remove_columns = []
dataset = load_dataset(path, name, streaming=True, split="train", token=token).with_format("torch")
print(f'{dataset=}')
batch = dataset.take(batch_size)
# print(f'{next(iter(batch))=}')

# - Prepare functions to tokenize batch
def preprocess(examples):  # gets the raw text batch according to the specific names in table in data set & tokenize
    return tokenizer(examples["link"], padding="max_length", max_length=128, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
def map(batch):  # apply preprocess to batch to all examples in batch represented as a dataset
    return batch.map(preprocess, batched=True, remove_columns=remove_columns)
tokenized_batch = batch.map(preprocess, batched=True, remove_columns=remove_columns)
tokenized_batch = map(batch)
# print(f'{next(iter(tokenized_batch))=}')

from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, SequentialSampler
dataset = tokenized_batch
print(f'{type(dataset)=}')
print(f'{dataset.__class__=}')
print(f'{isinstance(dataset, Dataset)=}')
# for i, d in enumerate(dataset):
#     assert isinstance(d, dict)
#     # dd = dataset[i]
#     # assert isinstance(dd, dict)
loader_opts = {}
classifier_opts = {} 
# data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, shuffle=False, batch_size=loader_opts.get('batch_size', 1),
#                         num_workers=loader_opts.get('num_workers', 0), drop_last=False, sampler=SequentialSampler(range(512))  )
data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, shuffle=False, batch_size=loader_opts.get('batch_size', 1),
                    num_workers=loader_opts.get('num_workers', 0), drop_last=False, sampler=None)
print(f'{iter(data_loader)=}')
print(f'{next(iter(data_loader))=}')
print('Done\a')
```

error:

```
dataset=<datasets.iterable_dataset.IterableDataset object at 0x7e42c2f21d20>
type(dataset)=<class 'datasets.iterable_dataset.IterableDataset'>
dataset.__class__=<class 'datasets.iterable_dataset.IterableDataset'>
isinstance(dataset, Dataset)=True
iter(data_loader)=<torch.utils.data.dataloader._SingleProcessDataLoaderIter object at 0x7e42c2f21660>
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/formatting/torch_formatter.py:68: UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).
  return torch.tensor(value, **{**default_dtype, **self.torch_tensor_kwargs})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in collate(batch, collate_fn_map)
    126         try:
--> 127             return elem_type({key: collate([d[key] for d in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for key in elem})
    128         except TypeError:

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
    126         try:
--> 127             return elem_type({key: collate([d[key] for d in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for key in elem})
    128         except TypeError:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in collate(batch, collate_fn_map)
    149 
--> 150     raise TypeError(default_collate_err_msg_format.format(elem_type))
    151 

TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-1153c5915bd8> in <cell line: 49>()
     47                     num_workers=loader_opts.get('num_workers', 0), drop_last=False, sampler=None)
     48 print(f'{iter(data_loader)=}')
---> 49 print(f'{next(iter(data_loader))=}')
     50 print('Done\a')

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    631                 # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    632                 self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 633             data = self._next_data()
    634             self._num_yielded += 1
    635             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    675     def _next_data(self):
    676         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 677         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    678         if self._pin_memory:
    679             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     40         else:
     41             data = next(self.dataset_iter)
---> 42         return self.collate_fn(data)
     43 
     44 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in default_collate(batch)
    263             >>> default_collate(batch)  # Handle `CustomType` automatically
    264     """
--> 265     return collate(batch, collate_fn_map=default_collate_fn_map)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in collate(batch, collate_fn_map)
    128         except TypeError:
    129             # The mapping type may not support `__init__(iterable)`.
--> 130             return {key: collate([d[key] for d in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for key in elem}
    131     elif isinstance(elem, tuple) and hasattr(elem, '_fields'):  # namedtuple
    132         return elem_type(*(collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in zip(*batch)))

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
    128         except TypeError:
    129             # The mapping type may not support `__init__(iterable)`.
--> 130             return {key: collate([d[key] for d in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for key in elem}
    131     elif isinstance(elem, tuple) and hasattr(elem, '_fields'):  # namedtuple
    132         return elem_type(*(collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in zip(*batch)))

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in collate(batch, collate_fn_map)
    148                 return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]
    149 
--> 150     raise TypeError(default_collate_err_msg_format.format(elem_type))
    151 
    152 

TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>
```

why is this error happening?

I've done all the checks, e.g., make sure the return indices are dicts, even went in detail debugging mode with pdb inside of pytorch's code.

- hf discuss: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-does-one-create-a-pytorch-data-loader-with-a-custom-hugging-face-data-set-without-having-errors/50204
- hf discord: https://discord.com/channels/879548962464493619/1139007085363875922/1139007085363875922

Comment: a small modification to this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76878652/1601580

Answer (score 0):

Without using a collate fn remove the columns so default collate works

```
def get_tokenized_dataset_to_work_with_pytorch_dataloader_by_removing_columns_without_tenosr():
    """
    Remove the columns that are not tensors, and then it works with pytorch dataloader.

    ref so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76872115/how-does-one-create-a-pytorch-data-loader-with-a-custom-hugging-face-data-set-wi
    """
    batch_size = 10
    token = open(Path('~/data/hf_token.txt').expanduser()).read().strip()

    # -- AF now
    from datasets import load_dataset
    import torch
    from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel
    
    tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    if tokenizer.pad_token_id is None:
      tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    probe_network = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    device = torch.device(f"cuda:{0}" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    probe_network = probe_network.to(device)

    # -- Get batch from dataset
    from datasets import load_dataset
    path, name = 'brando/debug1_af', 'debug1_af'
    dataset = load_dataset(path, name, streaming=True, split="train", token=token).with_format(type="torch")
    print(f'{dataset.column_names=}')
    batch = dataset.take(1)
    def preprocess_formalize(examples): 
        """ link,formal statement,generated informal statement,solvable by sledgehammer,keep or not,informalization correct """
        informal_statement = examples["generated informal statement"]
        formal_statement = examples["formal statement"]
        text = f'informal statement {informal_statement} formal statement {formal_statement}'
        return tokenizer(text, padding="max_length", max_length=128, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
    column_names = next(iter(batch)).keys()
    print(f'{column_names=}')

    # - Prepare functions to tokenize batch
    preprocess = preprocess_formalize
    remove_columns = column_names  # remove everything except the tokenized fields in the dict
    print(f'{remove_columns=}')
    def map(batch):  # apply preprocess to batch to all examples in batch represented as a dataset
        return batch.map(preprocess, batched=True, remove_columns=remove_columns)
    tokenized_batch = map(batch)

    # -- Get data loader
    from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
    data_loader = DataLoader(tokenized_batch, shuffle=False, batch_size=8, num_workers=0, drop_last=False)
    print(f'{next(iter(data_loader))=}')
    print('Done!\a')
```

otherwise write your own collate e.g.,

```
def demo_how_to_use_collate_fn_with_pytorch_dataloader():
    """
    so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76872115/how-does-one-create-a-pytorch-data-loader-with-a-custom-hugging-face-data-set-wi
    """
    batch_size = 512
    token = open(Path('~/data/hf_token.txt').expanduser()).read().strip()

    # -- AF now
    from datasets import load_dataset
    import torch
    from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel
    
    tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    if tokenizer.pad_token_id is None:
      tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    probe_network = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    device = torch.device(f"cuda:{0}" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    probe_network = probe_network.to(device)

    # -- Get batch from dataset
    from datasets import load_dataset
    path, name = 'brando/debug1_af', 'debug1_af'
    dataset = load_dataset(path, name, streaming=True, split="train", token=token).with_format(type="torch")
    batch = dataset.take(512)
    # column_names = next(iterbatch).keys()
    # print(f'{column_names=}')
    
    # -- Get data loader
    from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

    def collate_tokenize(data):
        text_batch = [f'informal statement {example["generated informal statement"]} formal statement {example["formal statement"]}' for example in data]
        tokenized = tokenizer(text_batch, padding='longest', max_length=128, truncation=True, return_tensors='pt')
        return tokenized
    data_loader = DataLoader(batch, shuffle=False, batch_size=8, num_workers=0, drop_last=False, collate_fn=collate_tokenize)
    batch = next(iter(data_loader))
    print(f'{batch=}')

    data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, shuffle=False, batch_size=8, num_workers=0, drop_last=False, collate_fn=collate_tokenize)
    batch = next(iter(data_loader))
    print(f'{batch=}')
    print('Done!\a')
```