# When using HF trainer, the logging for the train and eval do not show in charts, why?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, wandb, huggingface-trainer

I am trying to train my model and log both the train and eval loss (or ppl perplexity). But when I try it nothing in the charts except the system stats show.

Why?

Link to full code (should be fully contained):  https://github.com/brando90/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/blob/main/src/alignment/fine_tuning_with_aligned_data.py

Snapshot of most important code?

```
    # -- Training arguments and trainer instantiation ref: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.31.0/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments
    output_dir = Path(f'~/data/maf_data/results_{today}/').expanduser() if not debug else Path(f'~/data/maf_data/results/').expanduser()
    print(f'{debug=} {output_dir=}')
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=output_dir,  #The output directory where the model predictions and checkpoints will be written.
        # num_train_epochs = num_train_epochs, 
        max_steps=max_steps,  # TODO: hard to fix, see above
        per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=gradient_accumulation_steps,  # based on alpaca https://github.com/tatsu-lab/stanford_alpaca, allows to process effective_batch_size = gradient_accumulation_steps * batch_size, num its to accumulate before opt update step
        gradient_checkpointing = gradient_checkpointing,  # TODO depending on hardware set to true?
        optim="paged_adamw_32bit",  # David hall says to keep 32bit opt https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.11446.pdf TODO: if we are using brain float 16 bf16 should we be using 32 bit? are optimizers always fb32?  https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/is-there-a-paged-adamw-16bf-opim-option/51284
        per_device_eval_batch_size=per_device_eval_batch_size,
        warmup_steps=500,  # TODO: once real training starts we can select this number for llama v2, what does llama v2 do to make it stable while v1 didn't?
        warmup_ratio=0.03,  # copying alpaca for now, number of steps for a linear warmup, TODO once real training starts change? 
        # weight_decay=0.01,  # TODO once real training change?
        weight_decay=0.00,  # TODO once real training change?
        learning_rate = 1e-5,  # TODO once real training change? anything larger than -3 I've had terrible experiences with
        max_grad_norm=1.0, # TODO once real training change?
        lr_scheduler_type="cosine",  # TODO once real training change? using what I've seen most in vision 
        logging_dir=Path('~/data/maf/logs').expanduser(),
        save_steps=2000,  # alpaca does 2000, other defaults were 500
        # logging_steps=500,
        logging_steps=50,
        remove_unused_columns=False,  # TODO don't get why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76879872/how-to-use-huggingface-hf-trainer-train-with-custom-collate-function/76929999#76929999 , https://claude.ai/chat/475a4638-cee3-4ce0-af64-c8b8d1dc0d90
        report_to=report_to,  # change to wandb!
        fp16=False,  # never ever set to True
        bf16=torch.cuda.get_device_capability(torch.cuda.current_device())[0] >= 8,  # if >= 8 ==> brain float 16 available or set to True if you always want fp32
    )
    # print(f'{training_args=}')
    print(f'{pretrained_model_name_or_path=}')

    # TODO: might be nice to figure our how llamav2 counts the number of token's they've trained on
    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,  
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
        data_collator=lambda data: custom_collate_fn(data, tokenizer=tokenizer)
    )
    # - TODO bellow is for qlora from falcon, has same interface as Trainer later lets use: https://github.com/artidoro/qlora
    # from trl import SFTTrainer
    # peft_config = None
    # trainer = SFTTrainer(
    #     model=model,
    #     train_dataset=trainset,
    #     peft_config=peft_config,
    #     dataset_text_field="text",
    #     max_seq_length=max_seq_length,
    #     tokenizer=tokenizer,
    #     args=training_arguments,
    # )
    # TODO why this? https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/why-do-you-need-to-re-upcast-the-norm-layers-of-hf-falcon-to-fb32/46139
    # for name, module in trainer.model.named_modules():
    #     if "norm" in name:
    #         module = module.to(torch.float32)
```

cross: https://community.wandb.ai/t/when-using-hf-trainer-the-logging-for-the-train-and-eval-do-not-show-in-charts-why/5165

Answer (score 0):

fyi best solution I know:

```
    # - Get eval data set (AF for us), https://huggingface.co/datasets/brando/debug1_af
    per_device_eval_batch_size = 4  # TODO: change to something larger, right now due to size of my debug0
    eval_accumulation_steps=1
    eval_steps=1
    # eval_steps=1000
    # TODO: probably need to write a collate_fn for the eval so that the eval is done right?
    # TODO: we need ppl (and ideally token edit distance for eval, reason explained here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.15004)
    path, name = 'brando/debug1_af', None
    eval_dataset = load_dataset(path, name, streaming=False, split="test").with_format(type="torch") 
    eval_dataset = eval_dataset.select(range(per_device_eval_batch_size))
    ## eval_dataset = train_dataset  # TODO: fix obviously to something else using af
    raw_text_batch = eval_dataset.take(per_device_eval_batch_size) if streaming else eval_dataset.select(range(per_device_eval_batch_size))
    print(f'{raw_text_batch=}')
    print(f'{next(iter(raw_text_batch))=}')
    column_names = next(iter(raw_text_batch)).keys()
    def eval_preprocess(examples):
        return tokenizer(examples["formal statement"] + [' '] + examples["generated informal statement"], padding="max_length", max_length=max_length, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
    remove_columns = column_names  # remove all keys that are not tensors to avoid bugs in collate function in task2vec's pytorch data loader
    def map(batch):
        return batch.map(eval_preprocess, batched=True, remove_columns=remove_columns)
    eval_dataset = map(eval_dataset)
    train_dataset = train_dataset


    # -- Compute max steps
    per_device_train_batch_size = batch_size
    print(f'{per_device_train_batch_size=}')
    # dataset_size: int = int(1.5e12)  # TODO, doesn't seem easy to solve. Either count all the sequennces/rows or have the meta data have this. Or make this number huge. 
    dataset_size: int = train_dataset.num_rows
    # dataset_size: int = len(train_dataset)
    # TODO dataset.info['split']['train']['num_examples']
    # dataset_size = sum(len(dataset) for dataset in datasets)  # TODO: works on with streaming = False?
    # dataset_size = sum(dataset.cardinality() for dataset in datasets)
    print(f'{dataset_size=}')
    # # TODO: feel free to fix the issue if I'm not seeing all the data points...
    # num_epochs = 1
    max_steps = (dataset_size // per_device_train_batch_size) * num_epochs
    print(f'{num_epochs=} {max_steps=}')
    ## DOESNT WORK num_train_epochs = 3  # TODO: since I decided to do streaming = False and if we collect enough data it's unlikely we see it all hopefully (if we do 3 times seems good given that LLMs are trained to see the data only once this seems a sensible soln, + in the imagenet days things were trained to convergence with no overfitting ref: https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.00173)

    # -- Define custom collate function
    def custom_collate_fn(data: list[dict[str, str]], tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizer) -> dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
        """ trains on first occurence of eos
        
        ref: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/why-does-the-falcon-qlora-tutorial-code-use-eos-token-as-pad-token/45954/13?u=brando 
        ref: https://chat.openai.com/share/02d16770-a1f3-4bf4-8fc2-464286daa8a1
        ref: https://claude.ai/chat/80565d1f-ece3-4fad-87df-364ce57aec15 on when to call .clone()
        """
        # we are training full context length forllama so remove code bellow, if it triesto pad hopefully it throws an error
        # -- Ensure tokenizer has a padding token
        if tokenizer.pad_token is None:
            tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
        # -- Extract sequences
        # sequences: list[str] = [example.get("text", "") or "" for example in data]
        sequences: list[str] = []
        for idx, example in enumerate(data):
            # Retrieve the value for "text" from the dictionary or default to an empty string if not present or falsy. ref: https://chat.openai.com/share/bead51fe-2acf-4f05-b8f7-b849134bbfd4
            text: str = example.get("text", "") or ""
            sequences.append(text)
        # -- Tokenize the sequences
        tokenized_data = tokenizer(sequences, padding="max_length", max_length=max_length, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
        tokenized_data["labels"] = tokenized_data["input_ids"].clone()  # labels is hardcoded in HF so put it!
        # -- Set the mask value for the first eos_token in each sequence to 1
        eos_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id
        for idx, input_ids in enumerate(tokenized_data["input_ids"]):
            # Find all occurrences of eos_token
            eos_positions = (input_ids == eos_token_id).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]
            if eos_positions.nelement() > 0:  # Check if eos_token is present
                first_eos_position = eos_positions[0]
                tokenized_data["attention_mask"][idx, first_eos_position] = 1  # Set the mask value to 1
                
                # Assert that the label for the first occurrence of eos_token is eos_token_id
                assert tokenized_data["labels"][idx, first_eos_position] == eos_token_id, "The label for the first eos_token is incorrect!"
                
                # For all subsequent occurrences of eos_token, set their labels to -100
                for subsequent_eos_position in eos_positions[1:]:
                    tokenized_data["labels"][idx, subsequent_eos_position] = -100
                    assert tokenized_data["labels"][idx, subsequent_eos_position] == -100, "The label for the subsequent_eos_position incorrect! Should be -100."
        return tokenized_data

    # - Debug before training to see data
    sample_data = train_dataset.select(range(per_device_train_batch_size)) if not isinstance(train_dataset, datasets.iterable_dataset.IterableDataset) else train_dataset.take(per_device_train_batch_size)
    processed_data = custom_collate_fn(sample_data, tokenizer=tokenizer)
    print(f'{processed_data=}')

    # -- Training arguments and trainer instantiation ref: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.31.0/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments
    output_dir = Path(f'~/data/maf_data/results_{today}/').expanduser() if not debug else Path(f'~/data/maf_data/results/').expanduser()
    print(f'{debug=} {output_dir=} \n {report_to=}')
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=output_dir,  #The output directory where the model predictions and checkpoints will be written.
        # num_train_epochs = num_train_epochs, 
        max_steps=max_steps,  # TODO: hard to fix, see above
        per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=gradient_accumulation_steps,  # based on alpaca https://github.com/tatsu-lab/stanford_alpaca, allows to process effective_batch_size = gradient_accumulation_steps * batch_size, num its to accumulate before opt update step
        gradient_checkpointing = gradient_checkpointing,  # TODO depending on hardware set to true?
        optim="paged_adamw_32bit",  # David hall says to keep 32bit opt https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.11446.pdf TODO: if we are using brain float 16 bf16 should we be using 32 bit? are optimizers always fb32?  https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/is-there-a-paged-adamw-16bf-opim-option/51284
        warmup_steps=500,  # TODO: once real training starts we can select this number for llama v2, what does llama v2 do to make it stable while v1 didn't?
        warmup_ratio=0.03,  # copying alpaca for now, number of steps for a linear warmup, TODO once real training starts change? 
        # weight_decay=0.01,  # TODO once real training change?
        weight_decay=0.00,  # TODO once real training change?
        learning_rate = 1e-5,  # TODO once real training change? anything larger than -3 I've had terrible experiences with
        max_grad_norm=1.0, # TODO once real training change?
        lr_scheduler_type="cosine",  # TODO once real training change? using what I've seen most in vision 
        logging_dir=Path('~/data/maf/logs').expanduser(),
        save_steps=2000,  # alpaca does 2000, other defaults were 500
        # logging_steps=250,
        # logging_steps=50,  
        logging_steps=1,
        remove_unused_columns=False,  # TODO don't get why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76879872/how-to-use-huggingface-hf-trainer-train-with-custom-collate-function/76929999#76929999 , https://claude.ai/chat/475a4638-cee3-4ce0-af64-c8b8d1dc0d90
        report_to=report_to,  # change to wandb!
        fp16=False,  # never ever set to True
        bf16=torch.cuda.get_device_capability(torch.cuda.current_device())[0] >= 8,  # if >= 8 ==> brain float 16 available or set to True if you always want fp32
        evaluation_strategy='steps',
        per_device_eval_batch_size=per_device_eval_batch_size,
        eval_accumulation_steps=eval_accumulation_steps,
        eval_steps=eval_steps,
    )
    # print(f'{training_args=}')
    print(f'{pretrained_model_name_or_path=}')

    # TODO: might be nice to figure our how llamav2 counts the number of token's they've trained on
    print(f'{train_dataset=}')
    print(f'{eval_dataset=}')
    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,  
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
        data_collator=lambda data: custom_collate_fn(data, tokenizer=tokenizer)
    )
```

All links related to this Q:

- https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-sample-from-the-validation-set-when-using-trainer/25240/4?u=alvations
- [When using HF trainer, the logging for the train and eval do not show in charts, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77233053/when-using-hf-trainer-the-logging-for-the-train-and-eval-do-not-show-in-charts)
- https://community.wandb.ai/t/when-using-hf-trainer-the-logging-for-the-train-and-eval-do-not-show-in-charts-why/5165
- https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/15812
- https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/evaluate-subset-of-data-during-training/10952