# Do we need to explicitly save a Hugging Face (HF) model trained with HF trainer after the trainer.train() even if we are checkpointing?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-trainer

After I train my model, I have a line of code to train my model -- **to make sure the final/best model is saved at the end of training.** Is that really needed if I am using the trainer and check pointing flags?

My code:

```
    # -- Training arguments and trainer instantiation ref: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.31.0/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments
    output_dir = Path(f'~/data/maf_data/results_{today}/').expanduser() if not debug else Path(f'~/data/maf_data/results/').expanduser()
    print(f'{debug=} {output_dir=} \n {report_to=}')
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=output_dir,  #The output directory where the model predictions and checkpoints will be written.
        # num_train_epochs = num_train_epochs, 
        max_steps=max_steps,  # TODO: hard to fix, see above
        per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=gradient_accumulation_steps,  # based on alpaca https://github.com/tatsu-lab/stanford_alpaca, allows to process effective_batch_size = gradient_accumulation_steps * batch_size, num its to accumulate before opt update step
        gradient_checkpointing = gradient_checkpointing,  # TODO depending on hardware set to true?
        optim="paged_adamw_32bit",  # David hall says to keep 32bit opt https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.11446.pdf TODO: if we are using brain float 16 bf16 should we be using 32 bit? are optimizers always fb32?  https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/is-there-a-paged-adamw-16bf-opim-option/51284
        warmup_steps=500,  # TODO: once real training starts we can select this number for llama v2, what does llama v2 do to make it stable while v1 didn't?
        warmup_ratio=0.03,  # copying alpaca for now, number of steps for a linear warmup, TODO once real training starts change? 
        # weight_decay=0.01,  # TODO once real training change?
        weight_decay=0.00,  # TODO once real training change?
        learning_rate = 1e-5,  # TODO once real training change? anything larger than -3 I've had terrible experiences with
        max_grad_norm=1.0, # TODO once real training change?
        lr_scheduler_type="cosine",  # TODO once real training change? using what I've seen most in vision 
        logging_dir=Path('~/data/maf/logs').expanduser(),
        save_steps=2000,  # alpaca does 2000, other defaults were 500
        # logging_steps=250,
        logging_steps=50,  
        # logging_steps=1,
        remove_unused_columns=False,  # TODO don't get why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76879872/how-to-use-huggingface-hf-trainer-train-with-custom-collate-function/76929999#76929999 , https://claude.ai/chat/475a4638-cee3-4ce0-af64-c8b8d1dc0d90
        report_to=report_to,  # change to wandb!
        fp16=False,  # never ever set to True
        bf16=torch.cuda.get_device_capability(torch.cuda.current_device())[0] >= 8,  # if >= 8 ==> brain float 16 available or set to True if you always want fp32
        evaluation_strategy='steps',
        per_device_eval_batch_size=per_device_eval_batch_size,
        eval_accumulation_steps=eval_accumulation_steps,
        eval_steps=eval_steps,
    )
    # print(f'{training_args=}')
    print(f'{pretrained_model_name_or_path=}')

    # TODO: might be nice to figure our how llamav2 counts the number of token's they've trained on
    print(f'{train_dataset=}')
    print(f'{eval_dataset=}')
    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,  
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
        data_collator=lambda data: custom_collate_fn(data, tokenizer=tokenizer)
    )

    # - Train
    cuda_visible_devices = os.environ.get('CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES')
    if cuda_visible_devices is not None:
        print(f"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = {cuda_visible_devices}")
    trainer.train()
    trainer.save_model(output_dir=output_dir)  # TODO is this relaly needed? https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/do-we-need-to-explicity-save-the-model-if-the-save-steps-is-not-a-multiple-of-the-num-steps-with-hf/56745
    print('Done!\a')
```

---

Going to use

```
    # - Make sure to save best checkpoint TODO: do we really need this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77261009/do-we-need-to-explicitly-save-a-hugging-face-hf-model-trained-with-hf-trainer
    final_ckpt_dir = output_dir / f'ckpt-{max_steps}'
    final_ckpt_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    trainer.save_model(output_dir=final_ckpt_dir)  # TODO is this relaly needed? https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/do-we-need-to-explicity-save-the-model-if-the-save-steps-is-not-a-multiple-of-the-num-steps-with-hf/56745
    print('Done!\a')
```

---

## Bounty

> what is the standard way to save model and tokenizer optionally at the end of a training run even if saving ckpting during training is true?

---

refs

related: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/do-we-need-to-explicity-save-the-model-if-the-save-steps-is-not-a-multiple-of-the-num-steps-with-hf/56745

Comment: what is the standard way to save model and tokenizer optionally at the end of a training run even if saving ckpting during training is true?

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use `load_best_model_at_end` in your `TrainingArguments`.

See here: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments.load_best_model_at_end

As mentioned: While using this, you may have 1 additional model saved.

Comment: sorry this lacks details or direct reference to the title question to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save tokenizer I think you need to do:

```
tokenizer.save_pretrained(training_args.output_dir)
```

e.g.,

```
    # note: seems trainer doesn't save tokenizer automatically 
    trainer.save_model(output_dir=output_dir)  # TODO is this really needed? https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/do-we-need-to-explicity-save-the-model-if-the-save-steps-is-not-a-multiple-of-the-num-steps-with-hf/56745
    ## tokenizer.save_pretrained(output_dir=output_dir)  # ref: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/do-we-need-to-explicity-save-the-model-if-the-save-steps-is-not-a-multiple-of-the-num-steps-with-hf/56745/3
```

in addition, you probably need to do this to save the model on it's own directory:

```
    last_mdl_ckpt_path: Path = output_dir / 'final_ckpt'
    last_mdl_ckpt_path.mkdir(parents=True, exists_ok=True)
    trainer.save_model(output_dir=last_mdl_ckpt_path)
```